# NodeJS randomly doesn't work

Tags: node.js

I have a nodeJS app that randomly stops working. Sometimes there is no problem and it works properly and sometimes it outputs `Cannot GET /`. Why is this and how should i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely because of nodeJS's built in HTTP agent's connection pool limit, see [the nodeJS documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_class_http_agent).  Whereas python has a default connection limit of **100**, in nodeJS this is by default **5**.

See more info about this common problem [here](http://blog.mongolab.com/2013/11/deep-dive-into-connection-pooling/).

An easy way to solve this is by  increasing the http's maxSockets option to a higher number. Example:

```
var http = require('http');
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 100;
var server = http.createServer(myApp);
server.listen(80);
```

You can even set it to unlimited:

```
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = Infinity;
```

Answer (score 1):

> this is mainly beacuse you are trying to hit the URL before it get
>   registered in node. Wait till the server starts completly and then try
>   to hit the URL.